# how to change color in HSB color system

Tags: java

I am studying the sample code from the last answer on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123841/javax-swing-timer-repeats-fine-but-actionlistener-doesnt-do-anything)

to see how to make a good flashing button. That sample code use the following code to specify the colors:

```
           for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
            {                 
                clut.add(Color.getHSBColor(1, 1 - (i / N), 1));             
            }             
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
            {                 
                clut.add(Color.getHSBColor(1, i / N, 1));             
            }
```

**Color.getHSBColor(1, 1 - (i / N), 1)** is the place building the colors. The first parameter (Hue) of the **getHSBColor()** will specify the base color. So if I change it to **230**, the colors should be **blue** based colors; if it is **60**, the colors should be **yellow** based. But the sample program doesn't work as I expected. There is no flashing color changes after I set the Hue to different value.  Anybody knows why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Color.getHSBColor()` should receive floating point numbers from 0 to 1, so any value bigger than 1 will be treated like 1...

Take a look:

> The hue parameter is a decimal number between 0.0 and 1.0 which indicates the hue of the color. You'll have to experiment with the hue number to find out what color it represents.
>
> For example, setPenColor(Color.getHSBColor(0.56f, 1.0f, 0.8f));

source: http://www.otherwise.com/Lessons/ColorsInJava.html

For example, you could do:

```
        float hue = your_color/255; // if you want to use 0-255 range

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {                 
            clut.add(Color.getHSBColor(hue, 1 - (i / N), 1));             
        }             
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {                 
            clut.add(Color.getHSBColor(hue, i / N, 1));             
        }
```

Comment: Strange, but java doc says differently (h is for Hue): The s and b components should be floating-point values between zero and one (numbers in the range 0.0-1.0). The h component can be any floating-point number. The floor of this number is subtracted from it to create a fraction between 0 and 1. This fractional number is then multiplied by 360 to produce the hue angle in the HSB color model.