# Java Image/Text Pulsating Glow Effect (Graphics)

Tags: java, image, effect, glow, pulse

How would I make an `Image` have a pulsating effect to it? I already know how to draw an `Image` to the screen, so I just need to know how I can add a pulsating glow effect. Would I need to use tons of threads?

Also, how would I make some text have the same pulsating glow effect?

I want to be able to draw this to the screen so this needs to be a graphics object (`g.drawString(glowingText, x, y);`).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to provide some sort of example of what you want to do as your question is not really clear enough to provide much input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`AlphaTest`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228735/how-do-i-fade-an-image-in-swing/2234020#2234020) shows one approach using [`Alpha Composite`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/AlphaComposite.html); [`FlashTest`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123841/javax-swing-timer-repeats-fine-but-actionlistener-doesnt-do-anything/2124507#2124507) shows another using [`getHSBColor()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getHSBColor%28float,%20float,%20float%29). You can infer which is more popular.

Addendum: To get a pulsating glow behind some text or image, you'll want to vary the *background* alpha instead of the foreground. There's a related example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163544/re-paint-problem-on-translucent-frame-panel-component/2166500#2166500). I often use this [utility](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/composite) to preview the effects of different composite modes.

Comment: The links above point to [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Examples](http://sscce.org/)s.

Comment: Those are okay, but I am looking for a PULSATING GLOW behind some text or an image.

Comment: Ah, I see. I've elaborated above.

Comment: No, `Translucent` just shows how to make the background translucent. All you really need is `AlphaTest`, which shows how to use alpha and the Timer. Just set the composite before you paint the background and set it back to 1 when you draw the foreground. Edit your question to include your [sscce](http://sscce.org/).