# How to fade in graphics.fill call

Tags: java, swing, awt, java-2d

I'm doing the following to a `Canvas` object.

```
graphics.setColor(BLUE);
graphics.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, width, height));
```

**I'd like to fade in the fill colour to create a smooth transition from the canvas background colour to the new colour** (and possibly fade out whatever colour was originally there).

I've played with [this kind of thing](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/Fadeoutanimageimagegraduallygetmoretransparentuntilitiscompletelyinvisible.htm) (setting the graphics object's composite to an AlphaComposite which a `Timer` updating the `alpha` value every n milliseconds) but I get flickering.

I'm wondering what general concept I'm missing.

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Flickering will come, mostly from, a non-double buffered source, like a `JFrame` or `JApplet`.  Instead you should be ensuring that 1- You are painting to a surface which is double buffered (like anything that extends from `JComponent`) and 2- You are overriding the `paintComponent` method and calling `super.paintComponent`.  Take a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13203415/how-to-add-fade-fade-out-effects-to-a-jlabel/13203744#13203744) which uses `AlphaComposite` and does not suffer from flickering...

Comment: Or this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2124507/230513) that varies saturation.

Comment: `I'd like to fade in the fill colour to create a smooth transition from the canvas background colour to the new colour` - The [Fader](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16727190/131872) class does then when a component gains/loses focus.

Comment: Good tip on the `Fader` class, thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, how could you be using the AWT? It is quite outdated. I reccomend you switch to swing, mainly because swing has double buffering, which would remove your flicker.

Comment: What's the Swing equivalent of Canvas?

Comment: There is no specialized drawing class like there is in the AWT, so you are supposed to use `JPanel`. A final note: **DO NOT OVERRIDE `paint`.** If you do, lots of things will not work correctly. You should override `paintComponent` instead, which is what you are supposed to do and it works.

Comment: +1 for using Swing, `so you are supposed to use JPanel` - You would use JPanel if you need the custom painting and the component to act as a container. The more general component to use for custom painting would be `JComponent` - since it has no default functionality.

Comment: Marked as correct as you pointed out I wasn't using Swing. Swapping out to JPanel applied double buffering automatically so I'm a happy bunny again. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your application does exactly what you tell it to do. If you want to make a fade-in effect, you have to determine what kind of color changes you want to make, create a function which does it, and implement the fade itself.

I'd approach it like that:

```
class FadeEffect{

  int totalDurationMs;

  int elapsedDurationMs;

  Color initialColor;

  Color finalColor;

  Color getColor(int durationDelta) {
    elapsedDurationMs += durationDelta;
    if (elapsedDurationMs > totalDurationMs) {
      return finalColor;
    }
    double progress = 1.0d*elapsedDurationMs/totalDurationMs;
    return new Color( (int)(finalColor.getRed()-initialColor.getRed())*progress,
                      (int)(finalColor.getGreen()-initialColor.getGreen())*progress,
                      (int)(finalColor.getBlue()-initialColor.getBlue())*progress);
  }

  //getters, setters, etc
}
```

As for the flickering issue: make sure you are using double buffering - either in your component, or by manually drawing on a off-screen buffer (image) and only posting the image to the screen when the drawing is complete.

Here is a sample code from my Graphic2D app doing the double buffering:

```
private VolatileImage vImg;

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    if (gc==null) gc = this.getGraphicsConfiguration();
    do {
        boolean sizeChanged = false;
        sizeChanged = (vImg!=null&&(vImg.getWidth()!=getWidth()|| vImg.getHeight()!=getHeight()));
        if (vImg == null || vImg.validate(gc) == VolatileImage.IMAGE_INCOMPATIBLE
                || sizeChanged) {
            vImg = gc.createCompatibleVolatileImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
            vImg.setAccelerationPriority(1);
        }
        final Graphics gimg =  vImg.getGraphics();
        if (gimg instanceof Graphics2D) {
            renderContents((Graphics2D) gimg);
            gimg.dispose();
            g.drawImage(vImg, 0, 0, null);
        } else {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Rendering impossible, graphics are not of Graphics2D class");
        }
    } while (vImg.contentsLost());
    updateAnimationNo();
}
```