# Java Swing - Flashing icon not showing up

Tags: java, swing, timer, icons, glasspane

I am trying to flash the icon to the user using a GlassPane. I am running a `javax.swing.Timer` which basically performs this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    frame.getGlassPane().setVisible(true);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
       //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    frame.getGlassPane().setVisible(false);
}
```

Unfortunatly, if I sleep the EDT (current thread within the timer), the icon does not show, as in the `paintComponent` method did not manage to get invoked fully before the thread went to sleep. Therefore, when the next instruction kicks in, the glass pane is hidden, and, as a result, the icon is never shown. Is there a way to achieve what I want using this (similiar) approach?

Comment: More examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2234020/230513) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2124507/230513).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a `javax.swing.Timer`

```
public FlashTimer() {

    javax.swing.Timer flashTimer = new javax.swing.Timer(500, new FlashHandler());
    flashTimer.setCoalesce(true);
    flashTimer.setRepeats(true);
    flashTimer.setInitialDelay(0);

}

public class FlashHandler implements ActionListener {

    private int counter;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

        countrol.setVisible(counter % 2 == 0);
        counter++;
        if (counter > 3) {

            ((Timer)ae.getSource()).stop();

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Mental note - you need to reset the `counter` between runs ;)

Answer (score 3):

It should be obvious - use a separate Thread and do the "blinking logic" there but modify the UI in EDT. Here is a simple example (should be enough to understand the idea):

```
public static void main ( String[] args )
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame ();

    final JLabel label = new JLabel ( "X" );
    label.setBorder ( BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder ( 90, 90, 90, 90 ) );
    frame.add ( label );

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation ( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    frame.pack ();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo ( null );
    frame.setVisible ( true );

    new Thread ( new Runnable ()
    {
        public void run ()
        {
            for ( int i = 0; i < 15; i++ )
            {
                try
                {
                    setVisible ( false );
                    Thread.sleep ( 500 );
                    setVisible ( true );
                    Thread.sleep ( 500 );
                }
                catch ( InterruptedException e1 )
                {
                    //
                }
            }
        }

        private void setVisible ( final boolean visible )
        {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater ( new Runnable ()
            {
                public void run ()
                {
                    label.setVisible ( visible );
                }
            } );
        }
    } ).start ();
}
```

Comment: You could simply the process by using a javax.swing.Timer

Comment: @MadProgrammer i cannot (in case i use sleep statements) since Timer action body is performed in EDT. That is why i have used separate Thread. Though its easily doable with timer w/o sleep statements, you will just need to invert component visibility with each timer event. Anyway both approaches are possible and are correct...

Comment: you don't need sleep with the Timer, let the timer take care of the sleep and just respond to the ActionEvent.

Comment: This is a little circuitous, but it appears to be correctly synchronized. `javax.swing.Timer` hides the complexity.

Comment: @MadProgrammer thats exactly what i was saying :)

Comment: @trashgod heh, good to know that, but anyway - i doubt its a good way to do things :)