# JTable cell color change with events

Tags: java, swing, jtable, background-color, tablecellrenderer

I have created a `JTable` that contains financial instruments prices.
I have connected the table to an online broker, and I receive live feeds through the API.
My table now correctly displays cells values changing when a new price comes in (I have created an "InstrumentListener".
What I want is this: when a cell value changes, the cell background color changes for 150ms and then returns white. If the value is higher than the previous cell value, the color should switch to `Color1`, if the value is lower, the color should switch to `Color2`.

Answer (score 2):

The tutorial article [*Using Custom Renderers*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) shows how to change a table cell's background color. The tutorial article [*How to Use Swing Timers*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) shows how to mark time efficiently; invoke `setRepeats(false)` and restore the original color in `actionPerformed()`. From a human factors perspective, 150 milliseconds is a little short. Consider *fading* the color, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2234020/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2124507/230513), over a second or so.